# How to initiate a socket connection from server to client?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have setup a tcp socket between a client and a server, very basic. Client side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = "81.88.95.250"                      

port = 25000

# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))                               

# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
msg = s.recv(1024)                                     

s.close()
print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```

server side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket                                         

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()                           

port = 25000                                           

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))                                  

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)                                           

while True:
   # establish a connection
   clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()      

   print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))

   msg = 'Thank you for connecting'+ "\r\n"
   clientsocket.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
   clientsocket.close()
```

My target is to send notification from client to server, and that's easy. The difficult part is that I also need in some circumstances to start the connection from the server and to send a command to the client and this must be executed as soon as it is received, so I cannot setup a periodic "poll". But I'm quite confused on this part, because the client is behind a NAT, not exposed with a public IP.

Comment: TCP sockets are bidirectional. You can just send a message from the server to the client over the existing connection, without opening a new connection.

Comment: Nope. Because the command I need to send from the server is asynchronous. In other words, I need some time to initiate a command from the server to the client, not in response to a notification from the client.

Comment: What "nope"? As long as you keep the connection open, you can send any data at any time in any direction you want, that's how TCP sockets work.

Comment: So, do you mean I can just save the clientsocket and leave the connection open forever?

Comment: Yes! That's how you're supposed to do it.

Comment: Ok. I will test it. Maybe I would need to create 2 threads in the server, one for listening and the other one to send the asynchronous command to the client. Right? How can I accept your solution?

Comment: @FabioMarzocca Yes, you can use threads for that.  And you can't mark CodeCaster's solution as accepted unless it is posted as an answer rather than as a comment.